# Angular template form multiple validation on password field?

Tags: angular

I have requirement to apply multiple validation on password field in template form likewise

1. Required
2. Minlength should be 8
3. Maxlength should be 10
4. One character in uppercase
5. One character lowercase
6. One special character

Here is my HTML Code and I have applied required validation on that:

```html
<input type="text" class="user-form-control" name="password" [ngModel]="user.password" required />
```

Please help!.

Answer (score 0):

With a **template-driven form**, you can [create your own validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#adding-to-template-driven-forms) (see the examples in this link) ; or create a function like `isFormValid(): boolean` that return `true` when all your criteria are ok. It will look like:

```
isFormValid(): boolean {
  if(user.password.length > 10)
    return false
  if(!this.containUppercase(user.password.length))
    return false

  // ...
  return true;
}
```

You can bind it to your submit button like this:

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!isFormValid()">Submit</button>
```

So the submit button will be disabled if the form is invalid.

---

But at this time, I would advise you to use a **reactive form** that has built-in validation and `valid` property. Here is the [documentation on both forms validation](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation).